# Google Cloud Platform key expiry date problem

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, service-accounts, airwatch

When I upload the key I created for the service account in Google Cloud Platform when I am doing Android EMM Registration with G-Suite in VMWare Airwatch, I get an error "***The added or subtracted value results in an unrepresentable DateTime. Parameter name: value***".

In Google Cloud Platform, the key expiry date is automatic **1 January 10000**. How can I fix this or is there any other way to register with G-Suite?

Airwatch is accepting P12 key file, not JSON. I'm having this problem when uploading the P12 file to Airwatch.

Comment: Service account keys do not expire. The date `1 January 10000` is just a placeholder for that value. You cannot change the expiration date because there is no date supported to expire keys.

Comment: @JohnHanley I saw it as Dec 31, 9999 in some sources and in google cloud platform's documentation. How should i upload a key file to airwatch if i cannot change the date? Airwatch does not accept JSON

Comment: I cannot answer about Airwatch. I have never used it. If Airwatch is asking for a date, I dod not know. Service accounts do not have a date. In regards to Airwatch not accepting JSON, what does it accept? Google service account keys are either a JSON data structure or just the Private Key portion or for legacy P12, a certificate that wraps the private key.

Comment: @JohnHanley OK, thanks anyway. It is accepting P12.

Comment: You can download a service account in P12 (which is a legacy format) directly in the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, I downloaded P12 and I uploaded to airwatch a later i got the DateTime error that I wrote in the question.

Comment: In that case, you need Airwatch technical support. 1) The P12 format is legacy and might disappear in Google Cloud. That means they are way behind the times. 2) It looks like they have a bug in date processing. Their developers will need to look at that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this guide on how to create a JSON key in [service account](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/PATROL4GoogleCloudPlatform/10/creating-a-service-account-key-in-the-google-cloud-platform-project-799095477.html).

Below command shows the expiration date [expiration show](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#listing_service_account_keys)

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys list --iam-account <sa-name>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Also, if you are using a user managed service account, there is [no expiration date](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts#authentication_using_rsa_private_keys) on other words we can say forever.

I would recommend you use a user managed key and create a new Key. Creating a new key might have expiry like Dec 31, 9999 I hope will work for your use case.

Comment: Thank you, but airwatch accepts key files with P12 extension, not JSON. Is it possible to generate a P12 key file with a different expiry date?

Comment: Activate the Service Account in gcloud she'll using "gcloud auth activate-service-account " then create another key to check if the expiry date has changed or not.